# transformation fails without error message

Tags: xml, xslt, opera

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='Transformations\style.xsl'?>
<test>
</test>
```

and in the `Transformations` subfolder the stylesheets style.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:include href="Common.xsl"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML DIR="LTR">
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
        Just a test
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and common.xsl

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open the XML in Opera, it says

> This document had an invalid XSLT stylesheet. Error message from the XSLT engine:

and there's no further error message behind `:`. It works in IE and Firefox.

What could the problem be?

I have already tried looking in Dragonfly and the error console, but there's nothing.

Version information:
Opera 12.17
Windows 7 SP1 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagnosing the problem with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), focusing on non-success results, I saw that `Common.xsl` was not found. The path where Opera looked up the file did not include the `Transformations` folder.

[image: Process Monitor Screenshot]

This lead me to the stylesheet path in the XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='Transformations\style.xsl'?>
```

Replacing the backslash by a slash resolved the problem:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='Transformations/style.xsl'?>
```

The problem seems to be only for the included `common.xsl`. If the include is omitted, the transformation works with `style.xsl` only, even if a backslash is used.

As mentioned by @IanRoberts in the comment, Opera treats the `href` attribute as a URI and replaces the (invalid) file name `Transformations\style.xsl` by `Common.xsl`.

Comment: The `href` is a URI, not a file path, so it needs to be a forward slash.  I suspect what's happening is that the browser is able to load `style.xml` when you use the backslash, but then when it tries to resolve the relative URI `common.xsl` against the base URI `file:/path/to/Transformations\style.xsl` it gets `file:/path/to/common.xsl` (because under URI rules `to/` is the last directory segment in the URI).